# How do I get flat texture projection on a object without distortion?

Tags: node-editor, camera, texture-coordinates

I tried using Window Texture coordinate, but it changes scale if I zoom in or out. The Camera Texture coordinate works in with orthographic camera but gets distorted if I use perspective camera.

I want the texture to have a fixed scale and not be distorted like on orthographic mode.[image: The left one is orthographic and the right is perspective using camera texture coordinate]

Comment: What version and render engine?

Comment: 2.8 cycles, its the same in 2.7 cycles.

Comment: @Rc12 I have added a new answer, which may fit your requirements even better. Please take a look at it. [Sorry for beeing a year too late.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Window mapped Texture Coordinates. But you need to scale the X axis to get 1:1 ratio on your texture. The UV coordinates are 0-1 in screen space.

[image: Window UV]

[image]

Or if you need to scale the texture depending on the distance from the camera. This is a bit simplified material that have an arbitrary power node to adjust the otherwise hard to achieve FoV calculations.

[image]

Comment: If you zoom in or out using window coordinate the texture changes in scale. I want the texture to be projected from the camera and have constant scale. If you use camera coordinate in orthographic mode it acts like window but doesnt change scale.

Comment: @Rc12 Changes scale? Can you elaborate? The texture is fixed to the window - it does not change scale.

Comment: The texture IS constant but is bound to the window size. Do you need it to be scaled with the object distance or the pixel distance?

Comment: I want the texture to be fixed on the object. So If I zoom out, the texture on the object is same as when I am zoomed in. When using window I have more lines when zoomed in but less when zoomed out. I want it be be scaled with object distance.

Comment: Then you will need to scale the texture based on the object distance and the camera Field of Vision. It will be a complex setup that not only is a material since the camera position and FoV is not available in the material nodes (yet?)

Comment: @Jackdaw If you are ok with using cycles, then you may be mistaken. Please review the last node setup in [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176648/30849). The node setup is simple and it does not require additional user inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## Use the Texture Coordinates of your Camera

[image: camera coordinates node setup]

Add a texture coordinate node and choose the camera output. If all coordinates had the same depth values, then the texture won't be distorted. You can simply reduce the length of the coordinates so that their z value equals `1` by dividing the coordinate by their z value.

Use a Vector Math node for the division and you have scale and ratio invariant view coordinates.

---

You will notice, that the texture still changes when altering its scale. This is because the Z coordinate is 1 and it's beeing scaled. If you don't want that, then multiply the Z coordinate with 0 with a vector math multiplication node (set X and Y to `1` though, because we don't want to change them).

[image: vectormath mutliplication]

---

The setups above will still zoom in and zoom out. They don't change when the camera is moved, but change when the cameras focal length decrease or increases.

However, since we have the relation of the camera coordinates and the window coordinates we can counteract this by multiplying the coordinates with the quotion of a single dimension of window / camera.

The following node setup will produce axis-equal window coordinates independently of camera position, rotation, or focal length.

[image: scale and angle invariant]

It works perfectly in cycles, but causes some artifacts in EEVEE in the center due to zero division.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UV Project modifier:

[image]

Then in nodes you use UV mapping. This setup is independent of render resolution ratio.