# Shader that always faces the camera

Tags: shaders, texture-coordinates

Using the Texture Coordinate node, the Camera output almost does it, but there are some weird seams that form:

[image].

The Window output works better, but it squishes it based on the width height ratio. The "solution" provided in another [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131241/how-do-i-get-flat-texture-projection-on-a-object-without-distortion) is not exactly good.

Node setup:
[image: node setup]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your nodes please?

Comment: @Bruno https://i.imgur.com/AMgjLVO.png

Comment: As you see I am trying to link your question to the duplicate you mentioned. I have however added an answer, which I think should satisfy you. Please [have a look at it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176648/30849).

Comment: Please use the [Edit] link of your post and embed the screenshot with the Add image button.

Comment: @Leander That solved it, thanks!